# What code finishes connection

Tags: java, jmeter

There is a proprietary plugin in JMeter which wrongly closes connection.

When I tried to debug running JMeter client, all I got was that it happens in JMeterThread.java, in method run, in finally, when curentSampler variable is nulled.

```
currentSampler = null; // prevent any further interrupts
```

How can I debug, get the info what code triggers closing the connection?

I'm running JMeter with this debug settings:

```
DEBUG="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Then I connect to it with IDEA.

Comment: You can use the [debug sampler or debug postprocessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to inspect values of properties and variables during the run to aid debugging. Do remember to disable/remove them for your final test execution.